# Как получить Map ID блюда — количество заказанного при помощи Spring MVC forms или даже простого HTML?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Есть меню, для каждого блюда появляется input количества для заказа

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${Order}" method="post">
    <span th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
        <input id="number" type="number" value="42">
    </span>
</form>
```

Я знаю, что в коде нет `th:field`, потому что я не понимаю, как можно засунуть каждый `input` в `DishQuantityMap`, где ключ - id Блюда, а значение - количество заказанного.

```java
public class Order {
    private String userName;
    Map<Integer, Integer> DishQuantityMap;
}
```

Comment: Простите, а зачем так? Сделайте сущность `OrderItem` связанную `MANY-TO-ONE` с заказом, в которой будет храниться непосредственно Dish и количество. Ну и `Order` с пользователем, наверное лучше связать также.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Благодарю, Михаил, так и сделаю, сижу уже третий день, подскажите, пожалуйста, а как в таком случае передать с фронта Order?
 Я был бы крайне благодарен, если бы вы продемонстрировали хотя бы часть кода с Spring MVC forms. Интересует именно сама форма.
Нигде не могу найти даже примеров подобного.

Comment: у меня до понедельника(включительно) не так много времени будет. Если получится найти время - то обязательно напишу.

Comment: не знаю насколько помогут, но можете посмотреть в моих других ответах примеры форм объектов, которые работают с множеством элементов и с "вложенностью". Как пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1356962/radio-button-fields-thymeleaf-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-thfield-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82/1358905#1358905

Comment: @МихаилРебров помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @МихаилРебров, вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, посмотреть, почему-то послед добавления перестал работать JS:(
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374214/js-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-thymeleaf-thfield-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83