# JS перестал работать после добавления Thymeleaf th:field, почему?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Вот мой JS, просто увеличивается input="text" при нажатии на + и уменьшает при нажатии на -.

```
unction stepperDecrement(btn){
const inputEl = btn.nextElementSibling;
const calcStep =inputEl.step * -1;
const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
if(newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max){
    inputEl.value = newValue;
}

}
function stepperIncrement(btn){
    const inputEl = btn.previousElementSibling;
    const calcStep = inputEl.step * 1;
    const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
    if(newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max){
        inputEl.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Вот мой HTML до добавления th:field на элементе input ( для краткости показана только часть, относящаяся к вопросу )

```
 <div class="single-menu" th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/menu}" th:object="${order}" method="post">
        <button class="decrement"  onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
                        <input
                                type="number"
                                min="0"
                                max="100"
                                step="1"
                                value="0"
                                readonly/>
       <button class="increment"  onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg">Confirm order</button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Теперь я добавлю th:field, который просто кладет в key dishId, а в value - inputValue.

```
 <div class="single-menu" th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/menu}" th:object="${order}" method="post">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
                        <input
                               th:field="*{dishQuantityMap[__${dish.id}__]}"
                                type="number"
                                min="0"
                                max="100"
                                step="1"
                                value="0"
                                readonly/>
       <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg">Confirm order</button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

И у меня перестает работать мой JS[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Кнопки не нажимаются, value даже не показывается.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в понимании и исправлении проблемы.

CSS мало относится к вопросу, но решил добавить

```
/* Button */
.myContainer {
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    color: #302020;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
button {
    color: #ff7720;
    background-color: #d3d2d2;
    border: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.decrement {
    padding: 15px 5px 15px 25px;
    border-radius: 45px 0 0 45px;
}
.increment {
    padding: 15px 25px 15px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 45px 45px 0;
}
```

UPD:
**Если я убираю readonly и ставлю любое число в input сам, то + - начинают работать. В самом коде страницы я заметил, что value без значения, оно просто не работает.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я через пару часов освобожусь и посмотрю обязательно

Comment: @МихаилРебров
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70826941/value-attribute-is-missing-after-adding-thymeleafs-tag-thfield-to-input
Я тут описал без лишнего кода, может, так будет гораздо удобнее.